# Synchronize packages between different machines

Tags: init-file, package, version-control

I use emacs in different places and I want to have a similar setup and packages installed everywhere. I guess I can use a version control repository for the setup files. Since I use [Prelude](https://prelude.emacsredux.com/), that would be `~/.emacs.d/personal/`.

I don't know how to do with packages. Is there a file somewhere in `.emacs.d/` with the list of installed packages that I can use to make emacs in other machines to also install those listed there?

Comment: For me the installed packages are just part of my Emacs version control repository.  I byte-compile the packages with the oldest version of Emacs I want/need to use and also put the .elc files into the repository.  This offers maximum control and consistency.  The trade-off is the (relatively) large size of the repository.  My 6 year old git repository has a size of 120MB.  While I could probably get away with 1/10 of it if I wouldn't include packages, those few "wasted" megabytes really don't worry me.

Comment: I should add that while ELPA/MELPA/... are pretty popular nowadays, still not all packages are available through them.  So if you use a package that needs manual installation you might not want to replicate the effort on each new machine you use (plus for each package upgrade).  Again, an easy solution is to add the package to your Emacs version control repository.

Comment: Can't you just byte compile on site and get away with ignoring .elc files in git ?

Comment: @Vamsi: I put the byte-compiled files into the repository because some (non-ELPA) packages are a bit finicky to compile due to their dependencies.  For these I don't like to repeat the process if not necessary.

Comment: @paprika Could you provide some details how to obtain your setup? Do you add everything in .emacs.d plus .emacs to the repository and that's it?

Comment: @Vamsi: I described it over at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154097/whats-in-your-emacs/2277001#2277001).  Nowadays I install most packages from ELPA, they are kept in ~/.elisp/elpa.  Yasnippet's snippets are also under ~/.elisp.  Using a directory separate from ~/.emacs.d allows me to freely choose any structure I desire.  I also don't have to gitignore the volatile junk in ~/.emacs.d.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**For emacs 25 or newer [refer to this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10961/23)**. For emacs < 25 there's no automatically generated manifest file that you can synchronize to achieve the desired effect.

That said, something you can do is add calls to `package-install` in your emacs configuration itself.

```lisp
(package-install 'auctex)
```

The idea is that `package-install` is idempotent, so if the package is already present, nothing will actually happen.
Assuming you have such a call for every package you use (or at least the leaves in the dependency graph), that would effectively synchronize your packages across machines.

---

For multiple packages you can use the following:

```lisp
(setq my-package-list '(package1 package2 packageN))
(mapc #'package-install my-package-list)
```

Comment: I am surprised how much simpler this approach is compared to the solution suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10093312). Is there any difference? The snippet also uses `package-install`.

Comment: There have been changes to `package.el` since that linked answer.  It's possible that at the time `package-install` performed operations on existing packages, not just uninstalled ones.

Comment: This technique is unfortunately problematic -- even if the package-archives repository is uniform between machines and specified in SCM.  It does not assure that package versions are identical between machines.  The issue is that package versions are not specified; these individual packages may diverge over time and their dependencies may become incompatible.  This can happen quite easily on active package archives such as melpa.

Comment: @ctpenrose: Do you have a suggestion to avoid this problem?

Comment: @student I have minimized the problem by using melpa-stable and updating packages less often.

Answer (score 36):

I keep my .emacs.d directory in version control. Then, in my init.el and subsequent files I use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) to define package setup. Not only does use-package lazily load your packages, it will download them on demand if they don't exist from whatever package repos you've set up.

For example, I use go-mode, but not on every machine. In my init.el I have the following:

```el
(use-package go-mode
  :ensure t
  :config
  (progn
    (defun my-go-mode-hook ()
      (linum-mode t)
      (setq tab-width 4)
      (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save))
    (add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'my-go-mode-hook)))
```

This adds a mode hook, but more importantly, by specifying `:ensure t` it will download the package on demand.

To keep a machine in sync, you can just checkout or pull from the repo and start up Emacs. Any new packages will be downloaded and installed.

Comment: This is the solution I now use too, rather than Cask, primarily because (as T. Verron noted) Cask does not work (well) on Windows, and is yet another dependency.

Comment: This is the way I use also, but instead of doing `:ensure go-mode` that is repeating the package name, you can just specify `:ensure t`

Comment: Good point! This is an old answer. I'll update it.

Comment: You can also use the `:hook` keyword to simplify your code.

Answer (score 18):

In Emacs-25, there is the variable `package-selected-packages`, so you can customize this variable and use `package-install-selected-packages` to make sure they're installed.

Comment: Note that I see it, the name of that command is a little confusing. Can I change it to package-install-selected-packages?

Comment: Assuming you mean "Now" instead of "Note", yes.

Answer (score 9):

What you want to use is [Cask](http://cask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which lets you create a [Cask file](https://github.com/andschwa/emacs/blob/master/Cask) specifying which packages to install on `cask install`. It can be used to manage dependencies of a package, and "dependencies" of your Emacs configuration with ease. Put your Cask file in under version control, and install/update packages on a per-machine basis.

Comment: It is worth noting that (as of today) this solution doesn't work for windows machines.

Comment: I no longer use this solution, for your very reason (and that Cask is yet another dependency). Great for making packages; horrible for configuration management.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach would be the following: since I do not only want to synchronise my Emacs packages, but also other files (e.g. `.emacs`, `.bashrc`, but also other directories) between my server and my laptop, I started to use [`unison`](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), to sync the files and directories. So when working on my laptop I simple run `unison laptop` before anything else. My `~/.unison/laptop.prf` file has the following section for Emacs related files:

```
path = .emacs
path = .emacs.d
ignore = Path {.emacs.d/semanticdb}
```

Since my Emacs packages (and also my Emacs backups and bookmarks) are stored in `~/.emacs.d` this makes sure I've got everything on all my machines.

An alternative approach would be put the `.emacs.d` directory in a directory that is synced with OwnCloud, DropBox or any other file syncing service and then create symlinks from `~/.emacs.d` to that shared directory.

Answer (score 5):

I use a little trick "stolen" from emacs-starter-kit (I think):

```el
(defun maybe-install-and-require (p)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
   (package-install p))
  (require p))
```

So when I require a package, I simply use:

```el
(maybe-install-and-require 'magit)
```

On emacs startups, evaluating my config, `package.el` will provide to install magit if it's not installed.

You can find my configuration here:

https://github.com/mdallastella/emacs-config/

Comment: Following same philosophy, you could use 'paradox-require' from [paradox](http://endlessparentheses.com/require-feature-or-install-package.html)

Comment: Github link needs to be updated. Its giving a 404 error.

Answer (score 5):

While `package.el` is the standard way to install packages, you might also want to try `el-get` which is very useful for installing packages which are not (or cannot be) on elpa. This answer deals with synchronizing such packages.

The way you ensure that given packages are installed when using el-get is to add something like the following to you init file

```
(el-get 'sync '(packages))
```

where packages are the list of packages you want to be installed. This function is similar to `package-install` it installs the packages only if they are not already installed, otherwise it simply initializes the packages.

Answer (score 4):

I have this [`setup-packages.el`](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-packages.el) in my emacs setup which is a hybrid of code from [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/core/prelude-packages.el) and [Tomorokoshi's blog on Package Management](http://toumorokoshi.github.io/emacs-from-scratch-part-2-package-management.html).

`setup-packages.el` does the following:

- Create a directory for `elpa` packages if one doesn't exists and add it and its sub-directories to the `load-path`.
- Update `package-archives` list with Melpa.
- Check if you have all the packages listed in `my-packages` list installed. If a package is not installed, install it.

### How to implement

- Save the `setup-packages.el` below to your `~/.emacs.d/` directory.
- Set `user-emacs-directory`, `setup-packages-file` and `my-packages` variables in your `init.el` and do `(load setup-packages-file)`.

When you start emacs for the first time on a machine that does not have these packages installed, all the pacakges listed in `my-packages` will get auto-installed.

#### setup-packages.el

```el
;; setup-packages.el - Package management

(require 'cl)
(require 'package)

;; Set the directory where you want to install the packages
(setq package-user-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa/"))

;; Add melpa package source when using package list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

;; Load emacs packages and activate them
;; This must come before configurations of installed packages.
;; Don't delete this line.
(package-initialize)
;; `package-initialize' call is required before any of the below
;; can happen

;; Auto install the required packages
;; Method to check if all packages are installed
(defun packages-installed-p ()
  (loop for p in my-packages
        when (not (package-installed-p p)) do (return nil)
        finally (return t)))

;; if not all packages are installed, check one by one and install the missing ones.
(unless (packages-installed-p)
  ;; check for new packages (package versions)
  (message "%s" "Emacs is now refreshing its package database...")
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (message "%s" " done.")
  ;; install the missing packages
  (dolist (p my-packages)
    (when (not (package-installed-p p))
      (package-install p))))

(provide 'setup-packages)
```

#### init.el

You would need the following in your `init.el`:

```el
(setq user-home-directory  (getenv "HOME"))
(setq user-emacs-directory (concat user-home-directory ".emacs.d/"))
(setq setup-packages-file  (expand-file-name "setup-packages.el" user-emacs-directory))

;; A list of packages to ensure are installed at launch
(setq my-packages
      '(
        ;; package1
        ;; package2
       ))

(load setup-packages-file nil :nomessage) ; Load the packages
```

Answer (score 3):

I have ~/emacs directory which is mercurial-version controlled and contains everything my emacs setup consists of (~/emacs/site-lisp for manually downloaded libraries, ~/emacs/elpa for elpa-installed libraries, ~/emacs/etc/ for splitted .emacs, ~/emacs/dot-emacs.el which I symlink as ~/.emacs). It required some tweaking of some packages to have all important files inside this tree, but it works well. Those few bits which are machine-specific I have implemented by conditionals on system name.

So after I install/reconfigure/change anything, I simply commit pull/push all the changes between all machines I use.

Extra benefit is that I have complete history of my config and can go back/bisect/revert in case anything goes wrong.

PS mercurial seems particularly suitable as it has natural two-side pull/push, but similar setup should not be hard to achieve with git or any other dvcs.

Answer (score 2):

In order to mirror my config I decided to go for a different approach, using [Syncthing](https://ind.ie/pulse/); every change in any of my config files propagates to
any other of my pcs without having to care about it, so when I upgrade packages I only have to do it in one of the pcs.

Answer (score 2):

**RSYNC**:  Synchronize select folders/files using `rsync`, either over a home network or via `ssh` to a remote server.

`rsync` is a one-way synchronization utility that is able to **delete** files on the target, so please be sure to **back-up** your data on both the source and target locations, *and* thoroughly test using the `--dry-run` option, **before** doing the real thing.

To read about how to properly configure the `.authinfo` file, see  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/auth.html  An example `.authinfo` file contents (which may contain multiple different entries) is as follows:

```
machine mymachine login myloginname password mypassword port myport
```

Configure and use the function `rsync-remote` to synchronize over `ssh` to a remote server.  Or, use the function `rsync-local` to synchronize on the same computer or over a trusted home network.

```
(require 'auth-source)

;;; EXAMPLE:
;;;   (get-auth-info "12.34.567.89" "username")
;;;   (get-auth-info "localhost" "root")
(defun get-auth-info (host user &optional port)
  (let ((info (nth 0 (auth-source-search
                      :host host
                      :user user
                      :port port
                      :require '(:user :secret)
                      :create t))))
    (if info
      (let* ((port (plist-get info :port))
             (secret-maybe (plist-get info :secret))
             (secret
               (if (functionp secret-maybe)
                 (funcall secret-maybe)
                 secret-maybe)))
          (list port secret))
    nil)))

(defun rsync-filter (proc string)
  (cond
    ((string-match
       "^\\([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+\\)@\\([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+\\)'s password: "
       string)
      (let* ((user (substring string (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))
             (host (substring string (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2)))
             (password (car (cdr (get-auth-info host user)))))
        (process-send-string proc (concat password "\n"))))
    ((not (or (string-match "files\\.\\.\\.\r" string)
              (string-match "files to consider\n" string)))
      (with-current-buffer (messages-buffer)
        (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (when (not (bolp))
            (insert "\n"))
          (insert string)
          (when (not (bolp))
            (insert "\n")))))))

(defun rsync-remote ()
"Use rsync to a remote server via ssh.  Back-up your data first!!!"
(interactive)
  (let* (
      (host "localhost")
      (username "root")
      (port (or (car (get-auth-info host username))
                (number-to-string (read-number "Port:  "))))
      (source
        (let ((dir (expand-file-name (locate-user-emacs-file "elpa/"))))
          (if (file-directory-p dir)
            dir
            (let ((debug-on-quit nil)
                  (msg (format "`%s` is not a valid directory." dir)))
              (signal 'quit `(,msg))))))
      (target "/private/var/mobile/elpa/")
      (ssh "/usr/bin/ssh")
      (rsync "/usr/bin/rsync")
      (rsync-include-file "/path/to/include-file.txt")
      (rsync-exclude-file "/path/to/exclude-file.txt")
      (rsh (concat "--rsh=ssh -p " port " -l " username))
      (host+target (concat host ":" target)))
    (start-process
        "rsync-process"
        nil
        rsync
        "-avr" ;; must specify the `-r` argument when using `--files-from`
        "--delete"
        ;; The paths inside the exclusion file must be relative, NOT absolute.
        ;;; (concat "--files-from=" rsync-include-file)
        ;;; (concat "--exclude-from=" rsync-exclude-file)
        rsh
        source
        host+target)
    (set-process-filter (get-process "rsync-process") 'rsync-filter)
    (set-process-sentinel
      (get-process "rsync-process")
      (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (message "rsync-remote:  synchronizing ... done."))))))

(defun rsync-local ()
"Use rsync locally -- e.g., over a trusted home network.
 Back-up your data first!!!"
  (interactive)
  (let (
      (rsync-program "/usr/bin/rsync")
      (source
        (let ((dir (expand-file-name
                     (file-name-as-directory
                       (read-directory-name "Source Directory: " nil nil nil nil)))))
          (if (file-directory-p dir)
            dir
            (let ((debug-on-quit nil)
                  (msg (format "`%s` is not a valid directory." dir)))
              (signal 'quit `(,msg))))))
      (target (expand-file-name
                (file-name-as-directory
                  (read-directory-name "Target Directory: " nil nil nil nil)))))
    (unless (y-or-n-p (format "SOURCE:  %s | TARGET:  %s" source target))
      (let ((debug-on-quit nil))
        (signal 'quit `("You have exited the function."))))
    (start-process "rsync-process"
      nil
      rsync-program
      "--delete"
      "-arzhv"
      source
      target)
    (set-process-filter (get-process "rsync-process") #'rsync-process-filter)
    (set-process-sentinel
      (get-process "rsync-process")
      (lambda (p e)
        (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (message "Done!"))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/redguardtoo/elpa-mirror creates a local repository of all installed packages.

Usage is simple, just run `M-x elpamr-create-mirror-for-installed`.

On other machines, insert `(setq package-archives '(("myelpa" . "~/myelpa/")))` into your `.emacs` and restart Emacs.

Now on all the machines, you get exactly same version of packages.

Comment: Thank you, this is a wonderful answer for my use-case, `elpa-mirror` should be more widely known.