# How to deal with packages when manage .emacs.d file with version control system?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use `git` to manage my `.emacs.d` directory. I occur this problem:

Some package files are already managed by package-tools such as `el-get`,`package.el` via `git`.

- If I add them into my git repository, I met *the submodule problem*, which makes things complex.
- If I exclude these package files, when I sync back to another computer, I have to manually install all the packages.

How to solve this dilemma?

```
modified:   el-get/ace-jump-mode (untracked content)
modified:   el-get/ace-window (untracked content)
modified:   el-get/dash (untracked content)
modified:   el-get/f (untracked content)
modified:   el-get/flycheck (untracked content)
modified:   el-get/fuzzy (untracked content)
modified:   el-get/s (untracked content)
```

Comment: @lunaryorn, Dan this question is similar to question asked [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/408/synchronize-packages-between-different-machines) however it deals with a different package management system (el-get) as such I believe this is not a duplicate

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: debatable, but certainly possible.  If it gets a couple more reopen votes, I'll reopen it -- although the practical effect may be the same since OP already accepted your answer. (+1, by the way; not clear why OP isn't following the "upvote-and-accept" convention.)

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: actually, a preferable way to do this might simply be to have you add your answer to the original question ("Synchronize packages...") so that we can collect all of the relevant solutions in one place. If you decide to do that (I'll upvote it for sure), please add a little more preamble to yours to clarify when to use it.

Comment: @Dan I added an [answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5839/247) to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packages installed via `package.el` the approach described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/408/synchronize-packages-between-different-machines) would work. For packages installed via `el-get` you can use do

```
(el-get 'sync '(packages))
```

The above line is equivalent to `package-install` described in the above link. It ensures that the packages are downloaded and installed, it simply initializes the packages if they are already installed