# How to run an `after-save-hook` only when the buffer has been saved manually

Tags: hooks, saving

This question is inspired by https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5947/.

Assume that I have a function like

```
(defun do-some-actions () ()
(..put a copy of the current file in a specific folder...)
  )
```

And I would like that the above function to be run after saving files. The following hook can do the job:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'do-some-actions)
```

But in this way Emacs runs the function `do-some-action` even for the files which have not been manually saved. For instance when I install the packages via Melpa, Emacs itself saves some files with the name `package_name-autoloads.el` in the directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/package_name/` and even though these files have not been saved manually, the function `do-some-actions` is executed.

My question is about the possibility to prevent Emacs to this after-save-hook when the file has not been saved manually.

Comment: You can probably create a `my-save-buffer` wrapper function that first calls `(save-buffer)` and then does `do-some-actions` and bind that to `C-x C-s` in a specific mode map or as a [buffer-local binding](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/519/115).

Comment: Alternatively, define what "saved manually" actually means (it could cover multiple commands, to my mind; `M-x apropos-command RET save\|write RET` may help), and then test those conditions in your hook function (e.g. by checking whether the `this-command` value is a member of your list of "saved manually" commands).

Comment: @phils Thank you for mentioning `this-command`, indeed very useful command. What I had in mind by *manually saving* was saving via `save-buffer` (`C-x C-s`). I think your comment to test if `this-command` has been `save-buffer` is the answer of my question. If you are comfortable please feel free to convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @kaushalmodi thanks for your alternative solution which bypasses `after-save-hook`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you need to define what "saved manually" actually means. It could cover multiple commands, to my mind. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-command` <kbd>RET</kbd> `save\|write` <kbd>RET</kbd> probably includes all the typical cases.

Once you know which commands you're interested in, you could simply test the `this-command` variable in your hook function, to see whether its value is a member of your list of "saved manually" commands.

e.g.:

```el
(defun my-after-save-actions ()
  "Used in `after-save-hook'."
  (when (memq this-command '(save-buffer save-some-buffers))
    ;; put a copy of the current file in a specific folder...
    ))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-after-save-actions)
```

Comment: Isn't `called-interactively-p` what were looking for?

Comment: Nordlöw: How would that help?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: That's fine, but is a completely different approach with a very specific definition of "saved manually". `called-interactively-p` just isn't relevant to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution:

```el
(defcustom after-save-interactively-hook nil
  "Normal hook that is run after a buffer is saved interactively to its file.
  See `run-hooks'."
  :group 'files
  :type 'hook)

(defun save-buffer-and-call-interactive-hooks (&optional arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (save-buffer arg)
  (when (called-interactively-p 'all)  ;; run post-hooks only if called interactively
    (run-hooks 'after-save-interactively-hook)))

(global-set-key [(control x) (control s)] 'save-buffer-and-call-interactive-hooks)

(defun run-mode-specific-after-save-interactively-buffer-hooks ())

(add-hook 'after-save-interactively-hook 'run-mode-specific-after-save-interactively-buffer-hooks t)
```

that I use.

Comment: I'd suggest that if you've bound `C-x C-s` to a command you've written yourself, you could be reasonably sure that nothing is going to call that function *non*-interactively, unless you've written such code yourself (which would be pointless for this particular instance, of course).

Comment: That won't trigger in cases where saving is invoked by another command, such as `C-x #` in a server buffer, which is probably not what was desired.

Comment: @Nordlöw I have need to use the filepath of the buffer I am saving. It seems I need to switch from a -hook  to a abnormal -function to pass the buffer being saved
The call to add-function fails however

(add-function :after 'after-save-interactively-function 'run-mode-specific-after-save-interactively-buffer-hooks)