# How to pass the buffer being save to after save hook?

Tags: hooks

This question [How to run an `after-save-hook` only when the buffer has been saved manually](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/how-to-run-an-after-save-hook-only-when-the-buffer-has-been-saved-manually#) provides a way to have after-save hook run after pressing Ctrl-x Ctrl-s, in the answer [Here's an alternative solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22214).

However the hook cannot take a argument. I understand a -function is needed and `add-function` is to be used instead.
The argument I wish to pass to the function is the file path of the buffer being saved as I wish to rsync it to a remote compile server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to pass any arguments to anything. The new hook that you have created, `after-save-interactively-hook`, is called just after saving the current buffer. Any hook functions you add to that list can simply call `buffer-file-name` to get the name of the file visited by the current buffer. For more information, use `C-h f buffer-file-name` to view the documentation of this function.