# Export Emacs installed packages?

Tags: package

I am using emacs 24.4. I have added a large number of installed packages via the M-x list-packages directive over about a year of usage. I would love to export my installed packages list for use elsewhere. Copying my .emacs gives me some errors on startup, which jogs my memory to install certain things. I suspect I could copy the .emacs.d, but that seems like maybe a bad idea.

Is there a procedure or directive I can issue to dump the list of installed packages to a file that can be used to get them on foreign machines easily?

Comment: Related: [Synchronize packages between different machines](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/408/5296)

Comment: Copying your `.emacs.d` directory (or preferably putting it under version control) is generally a good idea. (It's also sensible to rename `~/.emacs` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` if you decide to do this.)

Answer (score 5):

The directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa` contains all packages installed with `list-packages`. You can copy this directory over.

I would probably also run something like `(byte-recompile-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa" 0 t)` (`0` means don't ask, `t` means force recompile) to byte-recompile everything because I believe there is some incompatibility of byte-compiled files between Emacs versions.

Comment: I have used this strategy several times since asking this question. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4):

I had a look through the `package.el` file and found the variable `package-alist`. This seems to be a list of all installed packages including packages that are required by packages that you have installed.

If all you want is a list of the package names installed the the following code will write out the names of the packages from this list to the `*Messages*` buffer.

```
(dolist (p1 (sort (mapcar 'symbol-name (mapcar 'car package-alist)) 'string<))
  (message "%s" p1))
```

I'm no Lisp programmer so I'm sure somebody can write a much better version of this code.

I've also started to use the [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#for-packageel-users) code with the `:ensure t` option in order to install all my packages on a new PC.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing could be to install package if not already installed, you should update your init file, and add those lines:

```
(defvar my-packages
  '(color-theme db-pg db kv magit-push-remote magit-tramp
                magit git-rebase-mode git-commit-mode pg
                pretty-lambdada projectile pkg-info epl dash
                python-mode rich-minority s yasnippet yasnippet-bundle
                use-package key-chord undo-tree guide-key move-text
                openwith ack ag aggressive-indent nginx-mode multiple-cursors
                smartparens with-editor haskell-mode)
  "A list of packages to ensure are installed at launch.")

(defun my-packages-installed-p ()
  (loop for p in my-packages
        when (not (package-installed-p p)) do (return nil)
        finally (return t)))

(unless (my-packages-installed-p)
  ;; check for new packages (package versions)                                  
  (package-refresh-contents)
  ;; install the missing packages                                                                               
  (dolist (p my-packages)
    (when (not (package-installed-p p))
      (package-install p))))
```

Modify the `my-packages` variable and add/remove the package you want to be installed. `M-x describe-variable package-activated-list` will give you the list of your currently installed package.

After that, the only thing to share is your init file. 
I hope it will help.

Comment: Oops i see that you did answer how to dump the list. Perhaps that should be made more prominent in your answer?