# Install packages automatically

Tags: package, use-package

I'm new to Emacs, and I'm storing my Emacs configuration in a GitHub repo. Whenever I move to a new computer, I want Emacs to install all packages I specify if they do not present on this computer. Pretty much like `PluginInstall!` in Vundle for Vim. Or like `pip install -r requirements.txt`. How can I do that?

I've just got my hands on Emacs. So if you know the answer, please provide some detailed instructions so I won't get lost.

Comment: Actually found a better one with more solutions: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/408/115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load packages with [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) you can add `:ensure t` to make sure the package is installed on your system (installing it if needed).  For example:

```
(use-package helm
  :ensure t)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out later. BTW, are you estokes from JS? Sorry if I took for the wrong person..

Comment: I'm not sure what JS is, so I'm probably somebody different.

Comment: haha. Thanks for the answer anyways. looks like there is a lot to get used to in emacs