# Automatic package install is not available, package exists

Tags: package

I want to automatically install packages that I don't have locally installed when I initialize Emacs. I use the following code to install some packages.

```el
(package-initialize)
(mapc #'(lambda (pkg)
           (if (not (package-installed-p pkg))
                     (package-install pkg)))
            (list
             'json-mode
             ; ...
```

However, when loading Emacs, Emacs says the package is not available for installation. However, it exists on the packages buffer.

```
error: Package `json-mode' is not available for installation
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your value for `package-archives`? If you haven't MELPA to it yet, you might need to do that first before calling the code in your question: `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)`

Comment: @waymondo I have melpa, elpa, and marmalade set before this snippet

Comment: [Related question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/408/115), [related solution](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3239/115).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most likely need a `package-refresh-contents` call to download the list of available packages first:

```el
(defvar my-useful-packages
  '(ace-jump-mode ace-jump-buffer ... ))

(defun my-check-and-maybe-install (pkg)
  "Check and potentially install `PKG'."
  (when (not (package-installed-p pkg))
    (when (not (require pkg nil t))
      (package-install pkg))))

(defun my-packages-reset()
  "Reset package manifest to the defined set."
  (interactive)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (mapc 'my-check-and-maybe-install my-useful-packages))
```