# autoload list of packages in Emacs 25.0.92

Tags: package, error-handling

According to [emacs.SE answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/410/9686) I am trying to make Emacs (version 25.0.92) autoload packages if they are not already installed on my computer. At my `.emacs` file now I have only:

```el
(package-initialize)

(require 'package)

(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))

(setq my-package-list '(nyan-mode dired+))

(mapc #'package-install my-package-list)
```

But have an an error:

> error: Package ‘auctex-’ is unavailable

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a `(package-refresh-contents)` call. If you not installing packages interatively via `M-x list-packages` (which automatically updates your local database for all packages available on `package-archives`), you need to do this refresh manually.

Comment: I would also recommend using `use-package` it will install missing packages and their dependencies. It is really great!

Comment: I'd also recommend you don't remove the default `gnu` archive, like you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JulesTamagnan said, you should not use `setq` as that will totally replace the default value of `package-archives`. You do not need to add Melpa if you are doing it only to install `auctex`. But if you want to add Melpa, use `add-to-list` as he suggested.

```el
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

The second missing piece is the call to `package-refresh-contents`.

Here is what I have:

```el
(require 'package)

;; Load emacs packages and activate them
;; This must come before configurations of installed packages.
;; Don't delete this line.
(package-initialize)
;; `package-initialize' call is required before any of the below
;; can happen

(defvar my-packages '()) ; POPULATE YOUR TO-BE-INSTALLED PACKAGE LIST HERE

;; Auto install the required packages
;; https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/core/prelude-packages.el
;; http://toumorokoshi.github.io/emacs-from-scratch-part-2-package-management.html
(defvar modi/missing-packages '()
  "List populated at each startup that contains the list of packages that need
to be installed.")

(dolist (p my-packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (add-to-list 'modi/missing-packages p)))

(when modi/missing-packages
  (message "Emacs is now refreshing its package database...")
  (package-refresh-contents)
  ;; Install the missing packages
  (dolist (p modi/missing-packages)
    (message "Installing `%s' .." p)
    (package-install p))
  (setq modi/missing-packages '()))
```

Comment: If I got (at only first startup) some warnings like `Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘nyan-animate-nyancat’` and `Warning (bytecomp): assignment to free variable ‘nyan-animate-nyancat’` -- does it matter?

Comment: @drobnbobn When you say "at only first startup", is that the startup when that package got installed? Or is it every time emacs starts up? If it is the latter, you should file a bug report for that package (e.g. open issue on its github) to have it fixed.

Comment: Only when that package got installed.

Comment: @drobnbobn In that case it is fine. But the dev should still try to fix those if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Auctex is not in the melpa package archive it is in the gnu package archive instead of

```
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

try

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
         'APPEND)
```

This will keep the gnu package repo in the list of package archives

Comment: Didn't help, same error.

Comment: Did you restart your emacs session in between attempts?

Comment: Surely I restart Emacs after changing `.emacs`. Also I reinstalled Emacs and tried again. Same result.

Comment: is the value of `package-archives` contain to `("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")`. If it does then I am not quite sure what to tell you, and I'll delete my answer. Sorry man

Comment: After I apply your answer the value of `package-archives` becomes both gnu and mepla variants. Did your answer works for your Emacs 25.0.92?

Comment: @JulesTamagnan The new link for Melpa package archive is `http://melpa.org/packages/` [[Reference](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started)].

Comment: @drobnbobn I'm on 25.1.50.1

Comment: @JulesTamagnan where did you get it?

Comment: @drobnbobn I use the git version, I am probably a bit behind master by now though.

Comment: @JulesTamagnan could you provide a link on git repository? Can't find..

Comment: @drobnbobn You can either clone from http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/emacs.git or get the latest pretest (25.0.92 as of today) from ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/. You have to manually build these.