# How to get the same Emacs environment on a different computer?

Tags: init-file, config

I'm a beginner in Emacs (using it for about 2 weeks now and loving it). As I update and expand my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file, the things that I write in there depend on certain packages that I installed from MELPA using `M-x package-install`, on `.el` files that I've written myself, etc.

My question is, should I in the future switch computers for example, what is the best way to seamlessly get the same exact Emacs environment on the new computer as I have now?

Comment: As long as you can move your `init.el` around (using git for example), this approach also works (based on `use-package`): http://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/my-emacs-configuration-with-use-package.html

Comment: One approach is to put your .emacs.d directory in Dropbox.  I've only used it across computers with the same OS.  Different flavors o f*nix should be ok, but you might have problems if you try to share across machines running OSes that are too different.

Comment: This question is very close to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/408/2710 .  Can you highlight the differences?

Comment: For the non-programmer such as myself, synchronizing emacs configuration and packages across three machines (two windows, one OSX) using Google Drive has been effective and reliable. This works because emacs and most of its packages are largely platform agnostic. Cross platform reproduction of an identical emacs experience requires only a few lines in the init.el file to resolve OS specific paths to the synchronized emacs package directory.

Comment: Your config is your entire `~/.emacs.d` directory, so use whatever method you prefer to synchronise that between machines.  (e.g. a Github repository, or a Dropbox folder, or whatever works best for you).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct solution is to use [`straight.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el), a package manager that I wrote to solve this problem. You can find more details about this in [another answer to this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34241/12534).

This answer, which was written months before I started work on `straight.el`, previously described a strictly inferior way of achieving a partial solution. This approach is described briefly below; I no longer recommend it.

Even if you don't want to use `straight.el`, you should at least adopt [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package). (Not that the two are mutually exclusive—I believe the cleanest setup comes from using both.)

---

Start by defining a list of packages in your init-file:

```
(defvar my-packages
        '(
          aggressive-indent
          avy
           .
           .
           .
          projectile
          undo-tree
          )
  "List of packages to be installed at Emacs startup.")
```

Then install them automatically:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(package-initialize)
(unless (cl-every #'package-installed-p my-packages)
  (dolist (package my-packages)
    (unless (package-installed-p package)
      (package-install package))))
```

If you keep your `init.el` file under version control, then syncing it to another machine will result in your packages being installed automatically. Of course, the versions that are installed will be completely different, and your configuration can't be expected to work out of the box as a result. This is a fundamental flaw of `package.el`, and is one of the reasons why this approach is bad. See again [`straight.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el). Note also that the code outlined above separates your package list from your configuration for those packages, making it harder to keep track of things in your init-file. This is another major disadvantage. See again [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package).

Comment: Thanks for the write-up! If I choose to host everything on Github, including the packages I downloaded from MELPA, will this retain MELPA's capability of auto-updating the packages on the new computer?

Comment: @space_voyager Yes, everything will still happen the same way. However: (1) when you clone to a new computer, Emacs won't *need* to download packages from MELPA, because they are already in the repository you just cloned; and (2) whenever you use `package.el` to update packages, you will have unstaged changes in your repository, and you will have to make a commit to include the package updates.

Comment: Great, thanks. One more thing: I thought MELPA does package updates automatically. Is this not the case?

Comment: @space_voyager: Well, of course the remote package repository will be updated, but the updated versions of the packages are not downloaded and installed on your local machine automatically. For that you need to `M-x list-packages RET U`.

Comment: Instead of using `radian-packages`, may I suggest using `use-package` instead? It lets you keep your package names and their configuration together. See the answer by @zck. Much better than keep the package names far from their configuration.

Comment: @omajid I agree. As I say at the beginning of my answer: "(Note: while I quite like my current setup, use-package looks extremely nice, and I'll probably be switching to it someday. See the other answers to this question.)" However, I don't that that what I have isn't bad for someone just getting started (uses native `package.el` instead of another package).

Comment: How does straight.el fit together with Nix/Guix? Should I use straight.el on top of one of them, or should I forgo straight.el in that case and use some tailor-made Nix/Guix solution in Emacs? (I'm a complete newbie to purely functional package management so I have almost no idea about how any of these tools work.)

Comment: @Lassi Short answer: use whatever you want to install Emacs; use `straight.el` only to install Emacs packages. Nix is a great idea, but it's not well-optimized for Emacs package development, as far as I know _(please correct me if I'm wrong)_. If you use a system package manager to install Emacs packages, you won't be able to just edit their source code and then commit and push your changes upstream. Last time I looked at a Nix configuration for Emacs packages, it seemed overly complex and generally inferior to the `straight.el` development experience. But, whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 11):

If you use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), you can move that file around from computer to computer, and when Emacs starts up, as long as you have internet access, it will pull in the packages and configure them.

First, set up the package library:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

And then bootstrap `use-package`:

```
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))
```

Now, instead of configuring Emacs and assuming packages are installed, use `use-package` to both install and configure them. For example, for some of my helm settings:

```
(use-package helm
  :ensure t
  :bind (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
         ("M-y" . helm-show-kill-ring)
         ("C-x C-f" . helm-find-files)
         ("M-s o" . helm-occur))

  :config
  (helm-mode 1)
  (setq helm-echo-input-in-header-line t))
```

Comment: Mind you, that gets the configuration (in `init.el`) across, but there's lots more to it. For example, this wont' port the dabbrev files, or your custom snippets or any of a ton of other thing.

Comment: Yes. If you have other files that are part of your configuration, you'll have to move them too, alongside your init file.

Comment: at that point, it again becomes a game of "which file is actually part of my configuration and how do I keep it in sync across my machines" :(

Comment: you should add `:ensure t` to the `use-package` declaration or set `use-package-always-ensure` to `t`. Otherwise it wouldnt automatically install on another system when copied the config over.

Answer (score 9):

## Next-generation package management with [`straight.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el)

After a long and frustrating struggle to use `package.el` + Quelpa to manage my packages, I bit the bullet and [wrote my own package manager](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el/graphs/contributors). It is intended to completely replace `package.el` by providing a package management experience that is superior in [almost](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#tldr-1) every way.

You can read the [very extensive documentation](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el) to learn about all of its features, but the most relevant one to this question is that `straight.el` focuses on **perfect reproducibility**. This means it should not matter whether you are starting Emacs normally, or starting it on a new machine, and that any local changes are version-controlled and can be reverted to a canonical state. Practically speaking, this is achieved by (1) cloning packages as Git repositories, and providing automated tools for managing their state; (2) using the init-file as the **sole source of truth** for package management state, with no mutable data stored elsewhere; and (3) using optional version lockfiles to specify exact Git revisions of every package, plus any recipe repositories and `straight.el` itself.

To get started, insert the [bootstrap snippet](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#getting-started), which will install and activate `straight.el`. Then, to ensure that a package is installed, simply place a call to `straight-use-package` in your init-file:

```
(straight-use-package 'projectile)
```

Yes, it's that simple. No dealing with `package-refresh-contents` or any of that garbage. If you remove this form from your init-file and restart Emacs, Projectile will **no longer be loaded** (unlike in `package.el`). This means you do not have to worry about your configuration somehow not working on a new machine because you accidentally depended on undeclared packages.

You can install packages whereever and whenever you would like, throughout your init-file (no need to declare a list of them at a single point). Of course you can also just do

```
(dolist (package '(ace-jump-mode ... zzz-to-char)) (straight-use-package package))
```

if you prefer the list. I however recommend that you use [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) to manage your package configuration. First you have to install it:

```
(straight-use-package 'use-package)
```

Then, since `straight.el` has built-in integration with `use-package`, the following "just works":

```
(use-package projectile
  :straight t
  :init (projectile-mode 1))
```

Once you've written your init-file to install the packages it needs, run `M-x straight-freeze-versions` to save a version lockfile to `~/.emacs.d/straight/versions/default.el`. You should keep this file under version control, since it will allow `straight.el` to check out the correct versions of all your packages, when you first launch Emacs on a new machine. (You can manually revert to the versions specified in the lockfile using `M-x straight-thaw-versions`.)

To support the idea of machine-local dotfiles that I mentioned in [my other answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27890/12534), `straight.el` offers a [profile system](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#the-profile-system). I still recommend using symlinks for your dotfiles (in this case, `init.el`, your local init-file if applicable, and the version lockfile if you want to use one).

If you're wondering how `straight.el` compares with other package managers, check out the [extensive comparisons section](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#comparison-to-other-package-managers). But there is [lots more documentation on everything else](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el), too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [cask](https://github.com/cask/cask) to manage your packages. Use git/github to source control and sync your emacs dotfiles.