# Syncronize on save

Tags: saving

Is there any extension or easy way to configure a feature like the Visual Code Studio's extension SSFTP?

The ideal behaviour should be like the following one, by using ftp or sftp:

- Allow a manual request for sync remote -> local a full folder or just a specific file (or set of files). Preferabily, if some local file is not in the remote folder, the remote file must not be removed.
- Allow a manual request for sync local -> remote.
- Allow a sync-on-save feature to make a local -> remote syncronization each time a file is saved. Ideally, that synchronization must be done even if there is no local changes to save (the sync must be always done).
- It should be possible to config the syncronization by using passwords or ssh keys, with or without a passphrase.

Comment: I use Emacs with `rsync` to manually synchronize certain files/folders recursively (with some exclusions) to my website on a shared server in cyberspace, and to my jailbroken iphone over usb, and to/from my desktop and 3 laptop computers over a network.  I see the manual describes several standard hooks such as `after-save-hook` .... perhaps there is a built-in hook that suits your needs.  Emacs may have some built-in synchronization that I am unaware of.  Here is the link to a basic setup using Emacs and `rsync` to manually synchronize:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5844/2287

Comment: @lawlist The server is a very old AIX without `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[shadowfile.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/shadowfile.el) could help. Note, that it cooperates with Tramp since Emacs 26.2 only.