# Allow user to interact with subprocess

Tags: shell-command, subprocess

I would like to call a subprocess, and that subprocess has some interactive behavior. Thus, I would emacs to parse the output of the subprocess, ask the user for input, and then hand that input back to the subprocess.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use something with `set-process-sentinel`, `start-process`, `set-process-filter`, ...  See the manual for those functions and also Google for examples.  Essentially, the process filter can look for a known string or strings and then offer the user the ability to interact within predefined parameters ....  Here is an `rsync` example of mine where I look for the password prompt using the process filter with predefined regex and then programmatically send the password with `process-send-string` to continue the subprocess:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5844/2287

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. Example is very helpful.