# Fetch configuration from remote (e.g. Github) at startup

Tags: ssh, remote, github

I have to work on multiple different machines and it would be nice to keep my .emacs file consistent everywhere.

**Question**: is there a package which allows to update the file at startup from a remote  location such as github or via ssh?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What should/shouldn't I do when keeping .emacs and .emacs.d in version control?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/293/what-should-shouldnt-i-do-when-keeping-emacs-and-emacs-d-in-version-control), [Synchronize packages between different machines](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/408/synchronize-packages-between-different-machines), and, to a lesser extent, [Keeping my .org files in sync across multiple computers](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/keeping-my-org-files-in-sync-across-multiple-computers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this outside of Emacs, with a wrapper script that pulls the updated config first.

Something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd ~/.emacs.d && git pull --rebase
exec /usr/bin/emacs "$@"
```

Then make this executable, name it emacs, and put it on your PATH before the real one.

Another option would be to have `init.el` do pretty much the same thing: `(call-process-shell-command "cd ~/.emacs.d/ && git pull --rebase")`, and then proceed to load the other files from under `~/.emacs.d/`. The downside of this is that `init.el` itself will not be reloaded. But if this is all that your `init.el` does, and you delegate everything else to files loaded from it, that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since I presume you are going to be `ssh`ing to these machines, I suggest you can take a look at [sshrc](https://github.com/Russell91/sshrc) which lets you take your local dotfiles along when you ssh into any server.